# Postgres query to check a string is a number

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone tell me the query to check whether a string is a number(double precision). It should return true if the string is number. else it should return false.

consider :

```
       s1 character varying;
       s2 character varying;

       s1 ='12.41212' => should return true
       s2 = 'Service' => should return false
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be a regular expression match:

```
select '12.41212' ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'
=> true

select 'Service' ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'
=> false
```

Comment: .123.456.789. will pass this regexp too

Comment: Postgres 8.4 when creating a view required "E"...due to error `nonstandard use of escape in a string literal`.  Also, i had to support `-` or `+` as prefixes...so this solved those as well: `select '-12.41212' ~ E'^([-+])?[0-9\.]+$'`;

Comment: all those results showing "1...2" as numeric

Comment: Though not initially asked by the OP, this solution will also fail strings like `'1E3'`.

Answer (score 34):

I would like to propose another suggestion, since `12a345` returns `true` by ns16's answer.

```
SELECT '12.4121' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; #true
SELECT 'ServiceS' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; #false
SELECT '12a41212' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; #false
SELECT '12.4121.' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; #false
SELECT '.12.412.' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; #false
```

Comment: add the +/- optional in front, and its perfect '^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$'

Comment: paracosmo is correct with his asertation, This is a far better answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

I fixed the regular expression that a_horse_with_no_name has suggested.

```
SELECT '12.41212' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; -- true
SELECT 'Service' ~ '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'; -- false
```

Comment: 3-5 seems to pass your expression.

Answer (score 11):

I've created a function to check this, using a "try catch".

The function tries to cast the text to "numeric". It returns true if the cast goes right, or return false if the cast fail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "sys"."isnumeric"(text)
RETURNS "pg_catalog"."bool" AS $BODY$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    x = $1::NUMERIC;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT  COST 100
;

ALTER FUNCTION "sys"."isnumeric"(text) OWNER TO "postgres";
```

Comment: Wow, the only answer using built-in type conversion. I just wonder if we can use type conversion without resorting to a pl/pgSQL function?

Comment: This answer works best for me because I'm coming from MS-SQL and have been used to TRY_CAST for numeric data. Glad to have a way to keep using a similar format!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check with exponential , +/- . then the best expression is :

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

resulting in:

```
select '12.41212e-5' ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$' ;
```

as true.

The expression is from: https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

You can check for other types of numbers, for example if you expect decimal, with a sign.

```
 select '-12.1254' ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$';
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select s1 ~ '^\d+$';
select s2 ~ '^\d+$';
```

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to accept double precision numbers, this should work fine:

```
select '12.41212' ~ '^\d+\.?\d+$'; -- true
select 'Service' ~ '^\d+\.?\d+$'; -- false
```

This would also accept integers, and negative numbers:

```
select '-1241212' ~ '^-?\d*\.?\d+$'; -- true
```

Comment: Regex '^\d+\.?\d+$' will not allow single digit numbers. Please use '^\d*\.?\d+$' instead

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Fernando's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302341/119725), this is a tiny bit shorter, does not need a variable to be declared and gives the exact exception type (for educational purposes):

```
create or replace function isnumeric(string text) returns bool as $$
begin
  perform string::numeric;
  return true;
exception
when invalid_text_representation then
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security invoker;
```