# Pull specific numbers from a column that has numbers and words

Tags: sql, postgresql

Column

1

7

f

3

2

c

1

d

6

4

e

g

b

I want to be able to filter this using the IN() operator in the where clause and pull out only the numbers. The column is a varchar so it is coming back as an error in postgres

Comment: [Postgres query to check a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975257/postgres-query-to-check-a-string-is-a-number)

Comment: Have you tried `in('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')` ?

Comment: Yes I get an error say the column is not INT and varchar. This is an example of what I am trying to do, the actual data has 30 k rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subquerying with this in the SELECT --- cast(substring(*column* FROM '[0-9]+') as int) and this in the WHERE *column* ~ '^\d+$' in the FROM as its own table. Pulling just the integers i needed from that with IN (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

`select substring(colname FROM '[0-9]+') from tablename`

Comment: Still getting a error

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Comment: try this one also select regexp_replace(name , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') from tablename;

Comment: You should explain a bit about WHY you think your answer is correct.

Comment: create table contacts(id int, name varchar(200));

insert into contacts(id, name) values(1, 'abc 123 cde 555 mmm 999');

select regexp_replace(name , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') from contacts;

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the numbers using the ISNUMERIC() function on the WHERE Clausule.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE ISNUMERIC(column_name)=1
```

As mentioned on the comments, this is for SQL Server, but you can create your own ISNUMERIC function in PostgreSQL following this example:

[isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)

Comment: I get this error: ERROR:  function isnumeric(character varying) does not exist

Comment: @RPr my bad, I did not see that you're using PostgreSQL and The code I proposed is for SQL Server. You can create your own isnumeric function in PostgreSQL using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql