# Sequelize how to use aggregate function on Postgres JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have created one table with JSONB column as "data"

And the sample value of that column is

> `[{field_id:1, value:10},{field_id:2, value:"some string"}]`

Now there are multiple rows like this..

What i want ?

> I want to use aggregate function on "data" column such that, i should
>   get

1. Sum of all value where field_id = 1;
2. Avg of value where field_id = 1;

I have searched alot on google but not able to find a proper solution.
sometimes it says "Field doesn't exist" and some times it says "from clause missing"

I tried referring like `data.value` & also `data -> value` lastly `data ->> value`
But nothing is working.

Please let me know the solution if any one knows,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes should be something like this, so you instruct it to run the function on a specific value:

```
attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.literal("data->>'value'")), 'json_sum'],
    [sequelize.fn('avg', sequelize.literal("data->>'value'")), 'json_avg']        
]
```

Then in WHERE, you reference field_id in a similar way, using `literal()`:

```
where: sequelize.literal("data->>'field_id' = 1")
```

Your example also included a string for the value of "value" which of course won't work. But if the basic Sequelize setup works on a good set of data, you can enhance the WHERE clause to test for numeric "value" data, there are good examples here: [Postgres query to check a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975257/postgres-query-to-check-a-string-is-a-number)

Hopefully this gets you close. In my experience with Sequelize + Postgres, it helps to run the program in such a way that you see what queries it creates, like in a terminal where the output is streaming. On the way to a working statement, you'll either create objects which Sequelize doesn't like, or Sequelize will create bad queries which Postgres doesn't like. If the query looks close, take it into pgAdmin for further work, then try to reproduce your adjustments in Sequelize. Good luck!

Comment: SequelizeDatabaseError: function sum(text) does not exist

Comment: @Rahul then cast it to int `sequelize.literal("data->>'value'::int")`

Comment: Giving null value, infact when i run this: SELECT (data->>'field_id') AS "json_sum" FROM "public"."my_table" it is giving null value instead of number

Comment: and query with ::int is giving below error
SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax forinteger: "field_id"

Comment: @Rahul You'll need to filter out non-integer values using the `where` clause, I linked to a related answer in my post