# SQL: case when nan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare the field_1 if it is >0, the convert the column to `timestamp`, `if NaN` or `else then NULL`.

I did the code below but nothing works.
Does anyone know how to do please?

```
CASE 
    WHEN field_1 > 0 and field_1 != 'NaN' then to_timestamp(field_1)::time
    ELSE NULL 
END
```

Comment: "nothing works" is not a valid Postgres message - what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: The real question is though: why are you storing a date/time value in a `numeric` column to begin with? You should be using a `timestamp` column for that.

Comment: Your code works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=40e90e710eb29058e40ebdedbbfe6936

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the same approach to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975464/3171172)

```
CASE 
    WHEN field_1::VARCHAR(255) ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' 
    AND field_1 > 0 
  THEN to_timestamp(field_1)::time
  ELSE NULL 
END
```

Comment: my colum,n is of type numeric, so can not use the **~** @cheganacasb

Comment: you see what i mean?

Comment: you can't use a regex to compare a numeric column. `NaN` is a valid "value" for a numeric value and `field_1 <> 'NaN'` is perfectly valid SQL

Comment: You can try to cast the number to VARCHAR. Adapted the suggestion.