# COUNT ROWS that ONLY CONTAIN numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count the number of rows in my table where the column name only contains numbers.

The name column is a text column and contains entries like; 'My Tour' 'My number 1 Walking route' and '1234'

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Using the example above, I'm expecting to return the name 1234 only as it's it the only name that contains just numbers.

But nothing is returning?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above like pattern looks more like a regular expression...)

Comment: I'm using pgadmin

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975257/postgres-query-to-check-a-string-is-a-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM my_table
 WHERE name ~ '^[\d]+$'
;
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, MariaDB

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp