# getting an error 'function is_numeric(character varying) does not exist. ' in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-administration

I have created a function in postgres with the below query but it says "function is_numeric(character varying) does not exist."
while executing the function.

I tried with **"isnumeric"** also, but no luck. same message.

Is there any alternate way to check whether the data value is numeric or not.

```
 v_stmt := 'update '||user$get_name_table( id )||
                  ' set err = err+1,err_val = err_val+1
                  where is_numeric('||u.column_name||')=0' ;
```

Comment: Have you checked this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975257/postgres-query-to-check-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: @qaziqarta, yes already did. But i am not sure how can I incorporate this in my code

Comment: Well, for example if you have permissions to add functions to your database, you can add a function from the link's answers

Comment: @qaziqarta, is there any alternate way to to achieve this?

Comment: You created the function. Please update the question posting that function. Also post the table description (ddl). Post each as text - **no images**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_numeric(pval text)
 RETURNS bool 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$   
declare 
    vval float8;
begin 
    select pval::float8 into vval;
    return true; 
exception 
    when others then 
        return false;
end 
$function$
;

select is_numeric('123') =>> true 
select is_numeric('25.8654') =>> true 
select is_numeric('H65D') =>> false
```